# Remove blank space under UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have regular `UITableView` with `UISearchDisplayController` in Navigation Controller. SizeToFit works on `viewDidLoad` normally, without any problems. But when i enter search a write some letters, it returns me items, that OK but size of tableview fails.

It is scrolling well, from the bottom to the top but when i reach last item, it stops in middle (it looks like 1 or 2 cells are missing but they are not) & `HorizontalScrollIndicator` also reach just the middle of tableview.

Any advice ?

Comment: try `[self setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];` on the viewcontroller that is presenting the search results table

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Could that spacing be the 20 pixel status bar height ? What's the code you use to determine the height of your tableView ?

Comment: I finally fixed it, just set added some px to the height of Tableview. I was little bit confused, that it was normal until i reached bottom. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that after you've provided some search parameters and manipulated your data source, you are missing a call for

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hard to tell without the code, but the tableView may be attempting to display rows that should not exist anymore - causing an error in cellForRowAtIndexPath